# Please help convert sql string a.3.1 to (a).(3).(1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I need help to add `(` and `)`  to each character/number in a string (excluding `.` from the string) . 
For example i need to convert the string `a.3.1` to `(a).(3).(1)`

I am using sql server 2008 r2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a [**`Replace`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function will work for you.

Replace all the `.` with `).(`. Then Append `(` and `)` parenthesis at the beginning and end of string respectively

```
select '(' + Replace('a.3.1', '.' , ').(') + ')'
```

- [**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37544/1)

Comment: Wav...this fantastic , exactely this is what i nedeed and thanks a lot for the quick reply.